# Is there an online video server that can show paneable extremely large videos?

Tags: video, webvideos, video-player

I want to turn a set of high-resolution satellite images of the Earth (10,000x10,000 pixels) into a time-lapse video. But instead of downsizing the images, I would like that people could zoom into specific areas of the video in real-time, and pan through it.

**Is that possible?**

**Is there any web player with such feature?**

I've seen videos of cameras that film in all directions and as the video plays you can choose in which direction to look. How is that technique called? Something similar would be extraordinary.

Comment: When it's done with still images it's called gigapixel images. The technique of filming in all directions is called different things, depending on the viewer - if it's a headset it's VR, clicking and dragging on the video is usually called 360 video. I haven't seen anyone combining the two, but I bet there's a startup somewhere doing it right now.

Comment: Sounds like you just want a 360° style picture

Comment: @TravisO Yes, but on a video, not a still picture.

Comment: Ok so how is this not a 360° videos like what YouTube allows?  Is this just a "I want 360 just like YT but higher res?"

Comment: @TravisO No, to start is not 360, it is just a zoomable video. Like when you zoom in a map, but this would be an animated map made out of thousands of sat images.

Answer (score 1):

With current technology no, you "can not"; and with more powerful technology it is a waste of resources.

You do not need to stream a gigapixel video, you need to stream a video, receive the new "interest" zone, process the coordinates and display a new version of the video. Even arrange different chunks of different videos.

This is what google maps, bing maps or other applications do. They do not send you all the photos of the planet, just the ones you need.

Comment: I agree with no-optimal usage of resources, but then how would he convert a maps-like image representation into a video? Maybe it is not a video but a zoom-able map first. Then he can have another slider (like Apple Time Machine) to go through time. And yes, he can then make the time slider to move through automatically at a fixed rate to give effect of a video.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Prezi](https://prezi.com/).

I think it might be the right tool for the job, as it allows for a nearly infinite canvas and has a user interface that allows for users to navigate around the canvas to view different media, video, photos, etc.

I'm not familiar enough with Prezi to give advice on a specific workflow. But it's the program I'd look at first.

A second option, would be to build it in Flash.